# How do I create a volume slider for an HTML5 video using Jquery and Hype

Tags: jquery, html, video, jquery-ui-slider

I'm  a complete beginner when it comes to Jquery, Javascript etc but I've managed to get a Jquery slider widget working in my page. Now I want to have that slider control the volume of a video which will be embedded as part of an animation in Tumult Hype. I know that Hype gives the video an 'element ID' that I can call from outside of Hype but I just need to know what code I should add to the Jquery Slider function to enable volume control of this video.
Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this:

```
$('#volSlider').slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        value: vid1.volume,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        range: 'min',
        animate: true,
        step: .1,
        slide: function(e, ui) { 
            vid1.volume = ui.value;
            if(ui.value > 0) vid1.muted = false;
        }
});
```

It assumes the ID of the video element is vid1.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, if this solves your problem, please consider making it the accepted solution. Thanks.